# Why maven use the old version of the Vaadin plug-in when I run the project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I use `Wildfly 20` and `IntelliJ latest` version with `vaadin-maven-plugin 14.2.2` in my `pom.xml` and `pnpm` enabled.

A very ugly problem happens what I can't understand why.
When I run my project via IntelliJ run configuration something strange happens. IntelliJ uses an older version of vaadin-plugin namely `vaadin-maven-plugin 14.2.0` which I don't have it in my pom.xml.

I have already tried `mvn help:effective-pom` to see if multiple versions of this dependency exists in pom and also checked all transitive dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`

**Anyone knows why this happens and what should I do to prevent it?**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <vaadin.version>14.2.2</vaadin.version>
</properties>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <pnpmEnable>true</pnpmEnable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <pnpmEnable>true</pnpmEnable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

If I use wildfly plugin and execut `wildfly:run` I get following error

```
    ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/flow-frontend/?babel-target=es5' in 'C:\workspace\user-web\target\frontend'
     @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js 45:0-32
     @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js?babel-target=es5
    ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/flow-frontend/?babel-target=es6' in 'C:\workspace\user-web\target\frontend'
     @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js 45:0-32
     @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js?babel-target=es6
Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.2.2:build-frontend 

    (default) on project user-web: Webpack process exited with non-zero exit code.
    Stderr: ''

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.Beta1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server-args>
                        <server-arg>-Duser.properties.file=C:\appserver.properties</server-arg>
                    </server-args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Ca not reproduce with given pom. How do you know the wrong plugin version is used? What Run Configuration do you use? The maven plugin version can be seen in Maven tool window next by the plugin: https://monosnap.com/file/zjVl1rsF1sdleZOGxOyUinJnMqFRAC What do you see there?

Comment: I see in maven tools version14.2.2 and when I run it, in the output of console I see old version 14.2.0. 
I did try with wildfly plugin there I get error: `Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.2.2:build-frontend (default) on project user-web: Webpack process exited with non-zero exit code.
Stderr: ''`

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

- Do `mvn clean install -U`
- Open the project view in IntelliJ
- Right click the pom.xml file and
- select Maven - Reimport If this works for you IntelliJ will add the
  dependencies to the project
- Check the if the dependencies you need are added in File - Project
  Structure - Project Settings - Libraries and File - Project Structure - Modules - Dependencies.

Comment: When I run `mvn clean install -U` get the following error.
ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/flow-frontend/?babel-target=es5' in 'C:\mediasoft\user-web\target\frontend'
 @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js
 @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js?babel-target=es5
ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports-fallback.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/flow-frontend/?babel-target=es6' in 'C:\mediasoft\user-web\target\frontend'

Comment: and this error:
Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.2.2:build-frontend (default) on project user-web: Webpack process exited with non-zero exit code.
Stderr: ''